# Audio is weak, Microphone is noisy

Tags: sound, microphone, realtek

I have just moved to  Ubuntu 22.04 from Windows 11. I have a Thinkpad E15 Gen 4 AMD. With Windows, both the speakers and the microphone were spectacular, since the laptop has a dolby sound. Since I moved to Ubuntu, the quality went down.
I used to see update the sound drivers in Windows as Realtek but in Ubuntu Settings they are called Family 17h Audio controllers.

I used `aplay -l` and got `ALC257` so I tried this https://devicetests.com/install-realtek-audio-drivers-ubuntu but I face the following error during `make` :

```
make -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-31-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/user/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa  CPP="gcc -E" CC="gcc" modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-31-generic'
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Makefile:711: syncconfig] Error 2
Makefile:789: include/config/auto.conf.cmd: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:812: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-31-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:167: compile] Error 2
```

Anyone has an idea what to do here?